# Not able to delete site collection using powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-collection

I am trying to delete a just created site collection but it keep giving me this error,

```
PS C:\Users\svc_spadmin> Remove-SPSite -Identity "http://intranet.sharepoint2010
.com/portalll/DeleteMe" -GradualDelete

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Remove-SPSite" on Target
"http://intranet.sharepoint2010.com/portalll/DeleteMe".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):y
```

> Remove-SPSite : Cannot open database "WSS_Content_SharePoint2010"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   'SP\Svc_SPAdmin'. At line:1 char:14
>   + Remove-SPSite <<<<  -Identity "http://intranet.sharepoint2010.com/portalll/De leteMe" -GradualDelete
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletRemoveSite:    SPCmdletRemoveSite)
>   [Remove-SPSite], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveSi    te

**Now if I logon to Central Admin and delete this site collection I don't have any kind of permission problem then why using powershell script ?**

**Edit**

When I try to add myself to db owner I get this error and don;t see DB in User Mapping table.

[image]

**Edit 2**

I logged in as Administrator which I used to install SQL Server but I can't find any permissions on Content DB even tho I am able to browse sites in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the account running the PowerShell has enough rights to perform the operation?

Have your tried an alternative stsadm?

```
STSADM -o deletesite -url <YOUR_SITE_URL_HERE> -force
```

Comment: I created this web application & site collection with using SPAdmin so I am not sure why it didn't added me to content db owners for this specific web app's content db

Comment: When I try to add myself as content db using SQL Server Management tools it still says I don't have permissions for content db, I can't see this content db in list either to add myself to it.

Comment: I added account SPAdmin to Content DB but still not sure why there was no permissions on content db at all, even tho there was no errors while creating it

Comment: What role SPAdmin has in your SharePoint installation?

Comment: Can't remember lol, but I just realized any web application I create, Content DB isn't getting any kind of permissions, but if I create a content db using powershell it gets SPFarm and another account. I can see SPAdmin in farm admins and its also a local admin too, maybe I need to add it to master database as owner too or problem could be because I installed SQL server using administrator account

Comment: I created a new question for it, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57785/content-db-not-getting-any-permissions-on-web-application-creation-through-centr