# Content DB not getting any permissions on web application created through central admin

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, content-database

I tried to create a Web Application using Central Admin. It created web app without displaying any error, I can browse site too after creating site collection and that, but content db got no permissions at all.

I am using SPAdmin account for creating Web App and also added it as SysAdmin in SQL server. If I create Content DB using Power Shell it gets right permissions I guess e.g. SPFarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a web application via GUI (CA) with windows authentication you have to be:

- a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group
- a member of the local Administrator group on the computer running Central
  Administration.

With PowerShell, you need to add permission using `Add-SPShellAdmin` command, and also make sure to be a member of the local Administrators group on the computer running Windows PowerShell.

I would recommend you to identify the main service accounts such as Application Pool account, Farm admin account, SP/SQL Server Installation account etc to identify the root cause of problem.

Happy SharePointing!

Comment: User is memeber of Farm Admin, local admin and sys admin in SQL server, most app pools are using SPFarm but couple are using SPService accounts, but my web app which I created is using SPFarm account

Comment: I stopped looking into it for the moment as I passed 70 - 667 exam but I might come back to it later on.